# What tools can I used to document ServiceStack web services?

Tags: servicestack

Which tools can I use to document ServiceStack web services?

Is there anything available in servicestack that can help?

I am currently using RestServiceBase version of ServiceStack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need something more the /metadata pages look at the [Swagger API support](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Swagger-API) in ServiceStack.

It should have no effect for this, but I'd recommend moving to the [New API](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/New-API) as RestServiceBase is part of the Old API that's been deprecated for some time.